# Receive telegram chat id c#

Tags: c#, telegram

How to automatically receive telegram chat.id with c# ?

Need that for SendPhoto from my bot to me in tg.

```
Bot.SendPhotoAsync(chat.id, new InputOnlineFile(imageFile, "Spotted.Png"), "AnStuffSpotted.");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have the Bot's token, you can create it and add this event handlers:

```
var bot = new TelegramBot(token);
bot.NewTextMessage += this.OnBotMessage;
bot.ChatMembersAddedMessage += this.OnBotMessage;
bot.StartReceiving();
```

When the chat has messages or a new member is added, this method will be invoked:

```
private void OnBotMessage(object sender, TelegramMessageEventArgs e)
{
    var token = this.tokenTextBox.Text.Trim();
    var chatId = e.Message.Chat.Id.ToString();
    var chatName = e.Message.Chat.Title;

    //SaveBotSettings(token, chatId, chatName);
}
```

You can use this method to save your token and chatId. You can save into a database or simply copy and use in your code (hardcoded in some const) depending of your needs. The chatId never change so the unique problem is get that id. Once you get, you can use forever.

Comment: Um, can u tell what telegram package u use? >.>

Comment: https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot. You can install through NuGet.